# Calling a method of Runnable object doesn't affect objects outside of it JAVA

Tags: java, reference, thread-safety, runnable

Given the code bellow, I Create two objects and ask the Swapper to swap between them.
Therefore the outcome should look like this:

```
1, 2
2, 1
```

but it appears to not work, and the outcome is two lines of "1,2".

The example we were given did swap between them, with the only difference of using an object that has a "get, set" function for the data inside it.

Is this not working because of the "set, get" functions not present, or would this not work either way?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    StringBuffer _i1 , _i2;
    _i1 = new StringBuffer("1");
    _i2 = new StringBuffer("2");
    Thread t = new Thread(new Swapper(_i1, _i2));
    System.out.println(_i1 + ", " + _i2);
    System.out.println(_i1 + ", " + _i2);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println(_i1 + ", " + _i2);
   }
}
class Swapper<Static> implements  Runnable {
StringBuffer _i1 , _i2;
Swapper(StringBuffer i1, StringBuffer i2) { _i1 = i1; _i2=i2;}
public void run(){
    synchronized (_i1){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (_i2){
            StringBuffer tmp = _i1;
            _i1 = _i2;
            _i2 = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `_i1` and `_i2` variables inside `Swapper` are not the same variables as the `_i1` and `_i2` variables inside `main`. Reassigning the swapper ones does not affect the main ones.

Comment: Since you're using mutable objects (StringBuffers), you could alter the contents of the two buffers instead of just reassigning the variables. That is presumably what you are supposed to do for this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct however there is an error in the scope.
There are `_i1` & `_i2` in both `main(){}` scope and `Swapper{}` scope.

The changed values of `_i1` & `_i2` in main scope are not assigned from the calculations.
Instead, try printing the values under `Swapper` class, after swapping the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I encourage you to get familiar with a [naming convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), use **only camel-case**, no `_i1` or anything along these lines.

The reason why your code isn't working is because you are confusing an **object** and a **reference to the object**.

You have two reference variables inside the `main()` method, and  two reference variables in the `Swapper`. Since in the method `run()` you are juggling with references but not changing the objects, the reference variables in `main()` stay unaffected because they still point to the same objects.

To change `i1` and `i2` you need to **change the objects** they are pointing to.

**Side notes:**

- The generic parameter `<Static>` is unused in your code and its name doesn't make any sense (it the same as `Swapper<T>` where `<T>` is just a placeholder for a type);
- don't synchronize your code against references that are being changed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    StringBuffer i1 = new StringBuffer("1");
    StringBuffer i2 = new StringBuffer("2");

    Thread t = new Thread(new Swapper(i1, i2));
    System.out.println(i1 + ", " + i2);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println(i1 + ", " + i2);
}

class Swapper implements  Runnable {
    private final StringBuffer i1;
    private final StringBuffer i2;

    Swapper(StringBuffer i1, StringBuffer i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (i1){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (i2){
                StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer(i1);
                i1.replace(0, i1.length(), i2.toString());
                i2.replace(0, i2.length(), tmp.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2
2, 1
```